# How does an abstract class behave in JVM environment? does it acquire space in class area when loaded by classloader?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

How does an abstract class behave in JVM environment? does it acquire space in class area(**method area in jvm**) when loaded by classloader?

Comment: *"does it acquire space in class area"* What's a "class area"?

Comment: ***sigh*** The point is that "class area" has no commonly-accepted meaning in the Java world. Say clearly what you're asking.

Comment: class area or method area in jvm memory

Comment: This is exactly the same question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756679/how-jvm-handles-abstract-class-in-java

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading a class consumes memory, yes. (For instance, as you mention, in the [method area](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.4), but not just there.) So does loading an interface (depending on whether it has default methods, it may or may not occupy any room in the method area, but it will consume memory. The class being `abstract` or not has no bearing whatsoever on the amount of space the *class* takes up when loaded. All `abstract` does is prevent you instantiating that class directly rather than as part of a subclass.